# How to add a custom library using add_block?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I created a custom library. This library contains only one subsytem block named RADAR. I am trying to use add_block and add this subsytem. Without any error the simulink file opens but the block does not appear.

This is how I load my library.

```
    load_system('libdeneme');
```

And these are some of the code lines I tried.

```
    add_block('simulink/libdeneme/RADAR','autoCreateDeneme')
    add_block('simulink/libdeneme/RADAR','autoCreateDeneme')
    add_block('libdeneme/RADAR','autoCreateDeneme')
    add_block('libdeneme/RADAR',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The source needs to be the library name then the name of the block in the library.  Your first 2 lines don't work because your library is not the `simulink` library.  But the source name in your last 2 attempts look right.

The destination needs to be the name of the model followed by the name to give the new block.  Neither of your examples follow that format.  (Surely the last example you give throws an error as it is invalid MATLAB syntax?)

You want something like

```
add_block('libdeneme/RADAR','nameOfModelToCopyTo/nameToGiveBlockInModel');
```

Comment: I tried this too. And it is still not working. Here is my coding.                                     >> open_system('libDeneme')
>> new_system('deneme')
>> save_system('deneme')
>> open_system('deneme')
>> add_block('libDeneme/RADAR','deneme/please')
There is no block named 'libDeneme/RADAR'
 
>> load_system('libDeneme')
>> add_block('libDeneme/RADAR','deneme/please')
There is no block named 'libDeneme/RADAR'
 
>> blockNames = find_system('libDeneme', 'Type', 'Block')

blockNames =

  1×1 cell array

    {'libDeneme/RADAR↵'}

>>

Comment: Solved the problem with some help. Thank you for your attention.